# Degenerate on the tangential directions of Laplacian operator

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Picture below is from **[Lectures on mean curvature flows](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/search.php?req=Lectures%20on%20mean%20curvature%20flows&lg_topic=libgen&open=0&view=simple&res=25&phrase=1&column=def)**.

What is the mean of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ? As definition, $g_{ij}=\langle \partial_i X , \partial _j X \rangle$. Why there are $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

Besides, how to understand the Laplace operator is degenerate on the tangential directions?  I can't understand the red line. In my view , a operator degenerate mean the determinant of coefficient of 2-order term equal to zero at some point.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: $X$ is a map into $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, so it has components $X^\alpha$. Looks like the authors are using Latin indices on $M$ and Greek ones on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis   I agree with you.  And I think the $\Delta$ should be $\Delta_{g(t)}$. And $g_{ij}$ is the induce metric, so , $|g_{ij}|>0$. Then when it is degenerate , only be $\partial_i\partial_j X^\alpha - g^{kl} \partial_kX^\alpha \partial_l X^\beta \partial_i\partial_j X^\beta$. But I still don't know why it is degenerate on the tangential directions. I don't know how to understand it .

Comment: The term being subtracted is the tangential projection of the first term, so when you plug in a tangential direction the symbol will be zero.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis  Thanks , I understand it .