# Trick of De Turck in mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

From this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187553/degenerate-on-the-tangential-directions-of-laplacian-operator),  I know the mean curvature flow is not strictly parabolic. For proving the short time existence ,by trick of De Turck, there is 
$$
\partial_t \bar X =g^{ij}(\partial_i\partial_j \bar X -\bar\Gamma_{ij}^k \partial_k \bar X)
$$
But why it is strictly parabolic ? I think I can do same thing as in  [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187553/degenerate-on-the-tangential-directions-of-laplacian-operator).

Besides, why $\Delta_{g(t)} \bar X = \Delta_{g(t)}   X$  in the middle part of picture below?

> [image]