# Some questions on mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, parabolic-pde, mean-curvature-flows

I am reading the book Lecture on mean curvature flow by Xi-Ping Zhu.
Suppose $M^n$ is an n-dim smooth manifold and $X(x,t):M^n \rightarrow R^{n+1}$ be a one-parameter family of smooth immersion. Metric and the second fundamental form on $X(x,t)$ is defined as $$g_{ij} = (\frac{\partial X }{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial X }{\partial x_j})\,\,\,\,h_{ij}= (n(x,t),\frac{\partial^2 X }{\partial x_i\partial x_j})$$
And the covariant derivative of vector $v$ is defined by 
$$\nabla_j v_i = \frac{\partial v_i }{\partial x_j} + \Gamma^i_{jk}v_k$$
1. How can i define the mean curvature $H$ by using the metric and second fundamental form ?

By setting $$\frac{\partial X }{\partial t}=H n$$
Using the Gauss equation and the Weingarten equation, we have 
$$g^{ij}\nabla_i\nabla_j X=g^{ij}(\frac{\partial^2 X }{\partial x_i\partial x_j}-\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial X }{\partial x_k})$$
2.How can i get the above relation?

3.Using the Gauss equation and the Weingarten equation, the author further calculate that 
$$g^{ij}(\frac{\partial^2 X }{\partial x_i\partial x_j}-\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial X }{\partial x_k})=g^{ij}h_{ij}n=Hn=\frac{\partial X }{\partial t}$$
Later he used the De turck trick to make this equation become strictly parabolic. But I think it is already strictly parabolic.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you well. If not , tell me.   Besides, if there is wrong in my answer, tell me too. Thanks.

First, the mean curvature can be written 
$$
H = g^{ij} h_{ij}
$$

Second, consider component $X^\alpha$ , treat it as function, so we have 
$$
\nabla _i \nabla _ j X^\alpha 
= \nabla_i (\nabla _j X^\alpha) - \nabla _{\nabla _i j}  X^\alpha   \\
= \frac{\partial ^2 X^\alpha}{ \partial x_i \partial x_j}
-\nabla _{\Gamma_{ij}^k \partial _k}  X^\alpha   \\
= \frac{\partial ^2 X^\alpha}{ \partial x_i \partial x_j}
-\Gamma_{ij}^k\frac{\partial X^\alpha }{\partial x_k}
$$
In fact, I don't know how connection act on a non-tangential vector.

Third,  you can see   Anthony Carapetis' comment of this   [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2187553/degenerate-on-the-tangential-directions-of-laplacian-operator).